# Solve $x^2+3y = u^2$ and $y^2+3x=v^2$ in positive integers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

The question is from the pg - 59 from ' An Introduction to Diophantine Equations ' by Titu Andreescu , Dorin Andrica , Ion Cucurezeanu.

> Example 1 : *Solve in positive system of equations in positive integers*
>
>  $$\begin{cases} x^2+3y = u^2 \\ y^2 + 3x = v^2 \end{cases}$$ 
>  $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(Titu Andreescu)}$ 
> Solution. The inequality $x^2 + 3y ≥ (x + 2)^2 , y^2 + 3x ≥ (y + 2)^2$
> cannot both be true, because adding them would yield a contradiction. 
> So at least one of the inequalities $x^2 + 3y < (x + 2)^2$ and
> $y^2 + 3x < (y + 2)^2$ is true. Without loss of generality, assume
> that $x^2 + 3y < (x + 2)^2$. 
>  Then $$x^2 < x^2 + 3y < (x + 2)^2 \implies
> x^2 + 3y = (x+1)^2$$ or, $3y = 2x+ 1$ . We obtain $x = 3k + 1, y = 2k + 1$
> for some nonnegative integer $k$ and $y^2 + 3x = 4k^2 + 13k + 4$. 
> For
> $k > 5, (2k+ 3)^2 < 4k^2 + 13k+ 4 < (2k+ 4)^2$ ; hence $y^2 + 3x$ cannot be
> a perfect square. Thus we need only consider $k ∈ {\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}}$ . Only
> $k = 0$ makes $y^2 + 3x$ a perfect square; hence the unique solution is
> $$x = y = 1,\;\;\;\;\;\; u = v = 2.$$

But if we take  , $$4k^2+13k + 4 = v^2$$ $$\implies k = \dfrac{-13 \pm\sqrt{105+16v^2}}{8}$$

Since $105+16v^2 = a^2 \implies 105 = (a-4v)(a+4v)$ which gives $a \in \{\pm11 , \pm13 , \pm19 ,\pm53\}$ .
Out of these , only  $a \in \{ \pm13 , \pm53\}$ works which gives $k=0,5$ , And so the the answer should be $$(x,y,u,v) = (1,1,2,2)\;\;\;,(16,11,17,13)\;\;\;\;,(11,16,13,17)$$

Who is correct here?

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1046718__4

Comment: The question fails to consider the case $k=5$, since you only eliminated $k>5$. This will give you the additional two solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You are indeed correct; it is not hard to verify that your solution(s) are indeed solutions. The proof that you quote overlooks the case $k=5$, which yields your two additional solutions.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{cases} x^2+3y = u^2 \\ y^2 + 3x = v^2 \end{cases}$  -----(1)

"OP" gave numerical solution to equation (1) as:

$(v,u,x,y)=(2,2,1,1)=(13,17,16,11)$

There is another numerical solution & is given below:

$(v,u,x,y)=[(10),(25/4),(13/4),(19/2)]$

Comment: Oops! I forgot to write the answers are positive integers only.